# Floating point exception error in C, although there is no %0 in the code

Tags: c

I know floating point exception error occurs only when something %0 has been done at any point in the program. But there is no such thing in my code. Still I'm getting that error. I'll be thankful if someone explains to me why this is happening.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int i, array[100], j; /*filling an array with 1 to 100 numbers.*/
    for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        array[i - 1] = i;
    }
    for (j = 2; j < 100; j++) {
        /* making multiples of numbers 'zero' in the array starting with 2 ,*/
        /* so in the end only prime numbers will remain in the array.*/
        for (i = j + 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            if (array[i] != 0) {
                if (array[j] % array[i] == 0) {
                    array[i] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment:  Please, easy on the ALL CAPS. It's considered YELLING.

Comment: No such thing? What is `array[i]%array[j]`? If the `j` index value is `0`, game over.

Comment: `array[i]%array[j]` This accesses element 100 which is out of bounds.

Comment: Also, `array[100]`, `j<=100` and  `array[j]` looks like a bad combination. The largest valid index for that array is 99.

Comment: `array[i]=0;` With `i` being ahead of `j` you can be sure to hit a 0 in one of the following iterations. Also for `i==100` you might hit `i` or `j` which are likely to be stored right before/after that array and then your loops might start again...

Comment: ARE YOU SURE?  WHEN YOU DIVIDE/MOD SOMETHING, LOAD THE DIVISOR INTO A TEMP VAR AND PRINTF IT OUT, JUST IN CASE YOUR ASSERTION OF NO DIV BY ZERO IS FLAWED.  THAT IS A VERY BASIC DEBUGGING STEP.

Comment: Your array indexes are out of bounds. This results in undefined behaviour which includes strange seemingly unrelated error messages. 1: Correct your array indexes, the first element of an array has index 0, not 1. 2: before the `array[i] % array[j]` check if `array[j]` is not 0. If it is 0 you'll get a "divide by zero error" which means something is wrong with your algorithm.

Comment: The point of the Sieve of Eratosthenes is to not check with numbers again that are already known to be non-prime. Skip them and your exception ist gone

Comment: ok got it .thank you all .

Comment: General advice: If people are unhappy with parts of your post: Go and correct it. Ecen as a new user you can edit your post as many times as you like. It shows respect for the readers who spend time with your problem and typically improves the question, making it more valuable for people with similar problems later (which is the whole idea of StackOverflow).

Answer (score 0):

If you change if(a[i]!=0) to if(a[i]!=0 && a[j]!=0), your problem will be fixed.